# Destroying button upon click (destroy error)

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I have a grid of buttons. After a button is right-clicked the goal is to create a new button on top of that with a flag image on it. Then after that button is left-clicked, I want to destroy that new button. Currently the right-clicking part works, but I'm getting the error "can't invoke "destroy" command: application has been destroyed" when I left-click. I looked through many questions and answers but can't figure it out.

```
def flags():
    for i in range(0,324):
        buttonlist[i].bind("<Button-3>", globals()[rightlist[i]])

def copy_function(fn, name):
    return FunctionType(
    copy(fn.__code__),
    copy(fn.__globals__),
    name=name,
    argdefs=copy(fn.__defaults__),
    closure=copy(fn.__closure__))    

for i in range(1,325):
    name = 'right' + str(i)
    def _right(event):
        global flag1
        flaglist[i-1] = tk.Button(app, text = "", width=16, height=18, image = flag)
        flaglist[i-1].grid(row=rowlist[i-1], column=columnlist[i-1], columnspan=1)
        flaglist[i-1].bind("<Button-1>", globals()[leftlist[i-1]])
    globals()[name] = copy_function(_right, name)

for i in range(1,325):
    name = 'left' + str(i)
    def _left(event):
        flaglist[i-1].destroy()
    globals()[name] = copy_function(_left, name)
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: why to create button on top of other button - change config in existing button - set emoty text and set image.

Comment: I don't understand why you copy function and why you use `global()` - better create normal dictionary to keep functions - code will be more readable

Comment: maybe instead of coping function better use lambda to assign the same function but with different argument(s) - `.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event:my_function(i-1)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you overcomplicated all code using `global()` and copied function.

You could use `lambda` to assign function with argument(s).

Because `lambda` is used in `for`-loop so it needs `y=row,x=col` to copy values to new variables. Without this all buttons would use the same values.

---

Minimal working code.

I uses button with text `X` instead image - this way every once can test it.

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- functions ---

def add_button(row, col):
    b = tk.Button(root, text=f' X ')
    b.grid(row=row, column=col)
    b.bind('<Button-3>', lambda event:b.destroy())
    
# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

for row in range(5):
    for col in range(5):
        b = tk.Button(root, text=f'{row},{col}')
        b.grid(row=row, column=col)
        b.bind('<Button-1>', lambda event, y=row,x=col:add_button(y,x))

root.mainloop()
```

---

Other method would be replacing configuration in existing button or use class `tk.Button` to create new class with all functions and then use it in grid.

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- classes ---

class MyButton(tk.Button):
    
    def __init__(self, master, row, col, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, *args, *kwargs)
        
        self.left_text = f'{row},{col}'
        self.right_text = ' X '
        
        self.bind('<Button-1>', self.on_left_click)
        self.bind('<Button-3>', self.on_right_click)

        self['text'] = self.left_text
        self.state ='left'
        
    def on_left_click(self, event):
        if self.state == 'left':
            self.state = 'right'
            self['text'] = self.right_text
            
    def on_right_click(self, event):
        if self.state == 'right':
            self.state = 'left'
            self['text'] = self.left_text
        
# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

for row in range(5):
    for col in range(5):
        b = MyButton(root, row, col)
        b.grid(row=row, column=col)

root.mainloop()
```